# How to insert tags into database using jquery html and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I want to insert these particular tags into the database. This is my HTML:

```
<div id="tags">
    <input type='text' name='tags' placeholder='Type in topic tags here seperated by commas' id="tagg" />
</div>
```

and the jQuery part:

```
 counter = 0;
    $(function(){
        $('#tags input').on('focusout',function(){    
        var txt= $.trim( $(this).val() ).replace(',','');
        if(txt){
        $(this).before('<span class="tag"  name="tags[]" value="'+txt+'">'+txt+'</span>');
        counter++;
        if(counter==5){
            $('#tags input').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        //$(".bgtopic").append("<input type='hidden' name='tags[]' />")
        //Yet to implement the counter varibale to be visible...
    }

    $(this).prop('value','');  
  }).on('keyup',function( e ){
    if(e.which==188){
      $(this).focusout(); 
    }
  });

  $('#tags').on('click','.tag',function(){
     $(this).remove();
     counter--;
     $('#tags input').prop('disabled', false);

  });

});
```

What the piece of code creates a tag when a user is creating a new post on my forum, just like the way it is here on StackOverflow. I want to be able to store the tags so that I can use them to create a tag cloud. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you considered using http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags or http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/ ?

Comment: nope lemme check them out

Comment: Try `select2` first as it's quite capable of doing pretty much everything. The GUI is great and the tags are stored in the `input` you attach `select2` to. So when you submit the form you only need to process the `input` with php - something like `$tags = explode(',', $_POST['tags']); foreach($tags as $tag) { //do some action }`

Answer (score 1):

you have to do an ajax request via jquery.

you can find a lot of tutorials on web how to do that (e.g. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/)